# Laravel wait for api response and continue

Tags: php, laravel

We have a large database where we track users' activities. A service presents activity data. The request to the service consists of 3 stages.

1. Create data request. POST /createList
2. Check if data has been processed. GET /checkList/listId
3. Retrieve data if processed. GET /getList/idlistId

Processing of data in the service usually takes 1 minute, but this time may be 30 minutes. As soon as this process is finished, I need to return the answer to my own user. Although "do while" seems to work for now, I don't believe it is a very logical solution. How can I do this with Laravel job?

Do I need to call the queue with cron job continuously?

my code:

```
$listService = new ListService();
$activityList = null;

// Request for generate the list
// Return listId
$res = $listService->createList('USER_ACTIVITY_LIST');
$listId = $res->getListId();

do {
    // control status of list.
    $checkList = $listService->checkList($listId);

    // If completed, create an ActivityList record
    if ($checkList->getStatus() === 'complete') {

        $data = $listService->getList($listId)->getData();

        $activityList = ActivityList::create($data);
    } else {
        sleep(10);
    }
} while ($checkList->getStatus() === 'pending'); // if it is not completed. try again

return $activityList;
```

Comment: `Retrieve data if processed` How are you doing this currently? Is it done via JavaScript on client-side, or are you not rendering page until data is ready?

Comment: Handled with Javascript. Skeleton is also waiting for loading until the result of the transaction is returned.